# Adding MouseListeners for JToolBar (events are consumed?)

Tags: java, swing, mouseevent, mouse-listeners, jtoolbar

When adding a MouseListener to a JToolBar,

```
jToolbar.addMouseListener(new MouseInputAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        log.debug(e.getPoint());
    }
});
```

The event only fires when clicked outside the JToolBar's gripper.

If I override BasicToolBarUI's createDockingListener():

```
@Override
protected MouseInputListener createDockingListener() {
    return new MouseInputAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
            log.debug(e.getPoint());
        }
    }
}
```

The event will fire when clicked on the gripper.

So my question is, why? Is the MouseEvent consumed in the dockingListener? But I don't see any code that consumes the event.

Comment: It's likely being consumed automatically by the event processing queue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `MouseEvent` is being automatically consumed by the `Container` at a number of points for a number of different reasons (some relating to how the native peer needs to deal with the event)...

Most notably in the `private` method `Container#processMouseEvent`, but it could be consumed before then

This basically means, when you attach a `MouseListener` to any component, it will consume all mouse events going to any component (or part thereof) that it resides above.

Think of mouse events like rain.  When a raindrop hits something, it stops.